# Media keys such as volume up/down , brightness up/down not working in kali linux on laptop

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, xfce4-terminal, media

I have dual booted kali linux with windows 11 and all the media keys combination and media buttons works fine in windows. I have also seen many people having the same issue as well, but the problem is something else i guess. When i tried kali linux as a live system from usb all the keys, buttons and other things worked great. Whats the reason for this weird behaviour, Did i miss something in installation process. Thanks and please help

Comment: Sorry I can't help with that, but to my knowledge kali is as much designed for autodetected media keys on random laptops as a penguin is designed to fly.

Comment: ok, i somehow found the solution. When i made a root user with admin rights(i am a windows person) all media keys worked great in that root user, i dont know why but it did

Answer (score 0):

I somehow found the solution. When i made a root user with admin rights(i am a windows person) all media keys worked great in that root user (not in the original-non root user), i dont know why but it did work